A finite sequence of rational numbers such that each consecutive two terms form a Farey pair
Let us consider the set $$ \mathcal{S}= \{(1,0),(0,1)\}\cup \{(p,q):p,q>0,(p,q)=1\}.$$
For $(p,q),(r,s)\in \mathcal{S}$, write $(p,q)<(r,s)$ if $p/q<r/s$ and $qr-ps=1$. Now suppose we have finitely many elements $(p_0,q_0),\dots,(p_n,q_n)\in \mathcal{S}$ such that $$ (0,1)=(p_0,q_0)<(p_1,q_1)<\cdots <(p_n,q_n)=(1,0)$$
Then is it true that $(p_{k-1},q_{k-1})<(p_{k+1},q_{k+1})$ for some $k\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$?
In terms of Farey sequences, it seems that this is equivalent to saying that if $\frac{0}{1}=\frac{p_0}{q_0},\frac{p_1}{q_1},\dots,\frac{p_n}{q_n}=\frac{1}{0}$ is a sequence of increasing rational numbers such that each $(\frac{p_i}{q_i},\frac{p_{i+1}}{q_{i+1}})$ is a Farey pair (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Farey_neighbours), then $(\frac{p_{k-1}}{q_{k-1}},\frac{p_{k+1}}{q_{k+1}})$ is a Farey pair for some $k$. Maybe should I try induction? The result is vacuously trivial for $n=1$, and obvious for $n=2$, but I cannot see how to use the induction step.
